# Print the second or nth match of a sed search which is based in between two patterns

Tags: command-line, bash, printing, sed

I would like to print the nth match of a sed search which is based on two patterns, as shown below:

```
sed -n '/start here/,/end here/p'  'testfile.txt'
```

Let's say that `testfile.txt` contains the text below:

```
start here
0000000
0000000
end here
start here
123
1234
12345

123456
end here
start here
00000000
end here
00000000

00000000
```

and that I do not want to print the zeros between the two patterns.

Based on the command above, I will get all the matches between the patterns, and its output is shown below:

```
start here
0000000
0000000
end here
start here
123
1234
12345

123456
end here
start here
00000000
end here
```

While my desired output is:

```
start here
123
1234
12345

123456
end here
```

Consider that the lines need to be printed as in `testfile.txt` and not concatenated.

Answer (score 7):

I'd solve this with Perl, as [@terdon](https://askubuntu.com/users/85695/terdon) sensibly suggests. Or with AWK:

```
awk '/start here/&&++k==2,/end here/' testfile.txt
```

If I had to employ sed alone (as the OP states in a comment) I'd come up with something much more convoluted, less readable and less customizable:

```
sed -n '/start here/{:A n; /end here/b B; b A}; :B n; /start here/{p; :C n; p; /end here/q; b C}; b B' testfile.txt
```

Comment: Really liked your awk sollution. Adjusted to my use case of getting the n'th SSL Certificate in a chain / crt-file: `awk -v n=2 '/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/ && ++k == n, /END CERTIFICATE/' /etc/pki/tls/certs/mychain.crt | openssl x509 -noout -text | grep -E '^  +(Subject|Issuer|Not Before|Not After ):'`

Answer (score 6):

I would just switch to another tool. Perl, for example:

```
perl -ne '$k++ if /Pattern1/; if(/Pattern1/ .. /Pattern2/){print if $k==3}' file
```

That will print the 3rd match. Change the `$k==3` to whatever value you want. The logic is:

- `$k++ if /Pattern1/` : increment the value of the variable `$k` by one if this line matches `Pattern1`.
- `if(/Pattern1/ .. /Pattern2/){print if $k==3}` : if this line is within the range of `/Pattern1/` to `/Pattern2/`, print it but only if `$k` is 3. Change this value to whichever match you want.

You could wrap this in a little shell function to be able to get the Nth match more easily:

```
getNth(){
  pat1="$1"
  pat2="$2"
  n="$3"
  file="$4"

  perl -ne '$k++ if /'"$pat1"'/;if(/'"$pat1"'/ .. /'"$pat2"'/){print if $k=='"$n"'}' file

}
```

You could then run it like this:

```
getNth Pattern1 Pattern2 3 'huge file.txt'
```

---

Using your example data:

```
$ perl -lne '$k++ if /start here/;if(/start here/ .. /end here/){print if $k==2}' testfile.txt
start here
123
1234
12345

123456
end here
```

Or:

```
$ getNth 'start here' 'end here' 2 testfile.txt
start here
123
1234
12345

123456
end here
```

---

Just for fun, here's another perl approach:

```
$ perl -lne '($k++,$l++) if /start here/; print if $l && $k==2; $l=0 if /end here/' testfile.txt 
start here
123
1234
12345

123456
end here
```

Or, if you like golfing (thanks @simlev):

```
perl -ne 'print if /^start here$/&&++$k==2../^end here$/' testfile.txt
```

Comment: Just for fun: `print if /^start here$/&&++$k==2../^end here$/`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this needs to be done through sed!

Comment: @dropdown why? Sed isn't the right tool for the job here. What are your requirements? What makes you say it _has_ to be done in sed?